# Android SDK Manager cant fetch Repositroy on Windows 8 x64

Tags: android, sdk, windows-8, connection

todey I installed the actual adt bundle on my Laptop which runs Windows 8 x64.
The installation worked well but when i start the SDK Manager he tries to fetch
the Android Repository and then I get this error:

```
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: Bind Cannot assign requested address: connect
```

I have tried the x86 and the x64 version of the SDK and none of it can fetch the repo. I have
completely reinstalled java. The funny thing I tried it on my windows 7 laptop it works
great. I also tried to force the SDK Manager to use http instead of https but it doesnt
help. I have also deactivated my Software Firewall (Kaspersky) and the Hardware Firewall
on my router and it doesnt help. Java can also connect do the internet because Jdownloader
can download without any problem. I also tried to open the URL in my browser and there were
no problems. Does anybody have an idea what else could be the problem?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem (I have eclipse Juno 64 bit, windows 8 64 bit and java 7u11).

I checked everything. I remember having a similar problem with Eclipse. I could not get a list of software to install no matter what I did or which web address I used.

The **solution** was to edit the `eclipse.ini` (located for me at `c:\Eclipse`) with the line `“-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true”` as the last line at the end of the file. So I tried something similar so I edited the android.bat file(Located for me at : `C:\Android\android-sdk\tools`) locate `“call %java_exe% ”` and add the line `“-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true”`.

So it should look like:

```
call %java_exe% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true %REMOTE_DEBUG% -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="%tools_dir%" -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir% -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*
```

save the file.

Run the android sdk as administrator and now I am downloading and installing all the bits I need.

Answer (score 1):

1) Could be a problem due to your computer's or organization's firewall. Try setting proxy in Eclipse->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Options if you have one.

2) Your antivirus might be blocking it try to disable it and retry.

Comment: Have you tried launching the SDK manager from file system and not through Eclipse?

Comment: for offline install of android SDK try this http://qdevarena.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html

Comment: I launched it directly and throught eclipse it doesnt work on both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Eclipse running in Drive C? Try running your eclipse or Android SDK manager as Administrator.